# Delay after choosing login method

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, login

This question might have been asked in the past, but I couldn't find it.

When clicking on "Login" on the stackoverflow website and then clicking on "StackExchange" for the authentication there is delay of a few seconds (when the dots are flashing) before the input fields are displayed.

What is the delay for?

Comment: Looks like it's sending a request to the server to check if you are already logged in. Not sure though, so just a comment.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I assumed that at first as well, but shouldn't that same check be made on almost every action for security reasons? There is no such deleay when selecting a question, though your details (like account name and reputation) are present on every page.

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed this a few minutes ago!